# ¿Cómo puedo setear o leer una variable useState desde otro lado en React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

A través de este botón quisiera cambiar el modo dark de mi app:

[image]

Tengo en un archivo js este código

```
const theme = createTheme({
    palette: {
        mode: dark ? 'dark' :  'light'
    },
```

El cual funciona si solo lo dejo
`mode: 'dark`

El punto es que quiero que cambie el modo con el botón que agregué en header, al cual le coloqué este código:

```
<IconButton edge='start' color="inherit" onClick={()=> setDark(!dark)}>
```

Y en mi App agregué un useState pero no sé cómo unir todo

```
import React, { Suspense, useState } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import { renderRoutes } from './routes/RouteUtils'
import routes from './routes/routes'
import { CssBaseline, LinearProgress } from '@mui/material'
import MainContextProvider from './Context/MainContext'
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles'
import theme from './theme/theme'



const App = () => {

    const [dark, setDark]= useState(false)

    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <MainContextProvider>
                <CssBaseline />
                <Router>
                    <Suspense fallback={<LinearProgress color="secondary" />}>
                        {renderRoutes(routes)}
                    </Suspense>
                </Router>
            </MainContextProvider>
        </ThemeProvider>
    )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es agregar dentro de tu función `App` el código para crear el tema y pasarlo al ThemeProvider.

Luego dentro de la función que crea el tema utilizas  el valor de la variable dark para validar si es Verdadera o Falso y modificar el tema de acuerdo a este valor

Para dichos efectos estoy empleando el hook [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo)

Y como empleas un provider principal `MainContextProvider`, puedes pasar la función `setDark` y `dark` como valor a través de este:

```
const App = () => {
  const [dark, setDark] = useState(false);

  const theme = React.useMemo(
    () =>
      createMuiTheme({
        palette: {
          type: dark ? "dark" : "light",
        },
      }),
    [dark]
  );

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <MainContextProvider value={{setDark, dark}}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <Router>
          <Suspense fallback={<LinearProgress color="secondary" />}>
            {renderRoutes(routes)}
          </Suspense>
        </Router>
      </MainContextProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Luego en en el componente donde planeas utilizar esta función consumes los valores que pasaste a través del `Provider`.
Para tal fin yo utilice el hook [`useContext`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext)

```
import React from "react";
import { IconButton } from "@material-ui/core";
import { MainContext } from "./Context";

const HeaderComponent = () => {
  const { setDark, dark } = React.useContext(MainContext);

  return (
    <IconButton edge="start" color="inherit" onClick={() => setDark(!dark)}>
      HOLA
    </IconButton>
  );
};

export default HeaderComponent;
```

Esta es la estructura de mi archivo Context que utilice como ejemplo:

```
import React from "react";

export const MainContext = React.createContext();
export const MainContextProvider = MainContext.Provider;
```

Acá te dejo el sandbox de la solución para le des una ojeada!

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-dark-theme-forked-hybl7o

---

#### UPDATE 1

Después de revisar el código de tu `Provider`, pude constatar que es un componente de Orden Superior el cual retorna el `Provider` y envuelve a los demás componentes, por ende debes pasar estos valores por las props de `MainContextProvider` y pasarlas al `MainProvider`

```
export const MainContextProvider = (props) => {
  const {dark, setDark} = props.value;  // Justo aca accedes a los valores que pasas por props
  const initialState = initStateFromLocalStorage();
  const [globalState, globalDispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  const saveStateToLocalStorage = () => {
    if (typeof globalState.auth.id === "undefined") {
      localStorage.clear();
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem("auth", JSON.stringify(globalState.auth));
    }
  };
  useEffect(saveStateToLocalStorage, [globalState.auth]);
  return (
    <MainProvider value={{ globalState, globalDispatch, dark, setDark }}> {/* Y ACA PASAS LOS VALORES AL PROVIDER */}
      {props.children}
    </MainProvider>
  );
};
export default MainContextProvider;
```

Comment: Hola GmrYael, gracias por tu ayuda!. Respecto a tu respuesta, hice todo lo que me sugeriste y en mi header agregue todo tal cual. 
`const { setDarkMode, dark } = useContext(MainContext);
return (
<IconButton edge='start' color="inherit" onClick={() => setDarkMode(!dark)}>       <Brightness6Icon />
</IconButton>`
Pero al presionar el botón me arroja este error
Uncaught TypeError: setDarkMode is not a function at onClick (Header.jsx:83:62)
La linea 83 de mi Header es esta `<IconButton edge='start' color="inherit" onClick={() => setDarkMode(!dark)}>`

Comment: Hola Walter, corregí el código. Es `setDark` en lugar de `setDarkMode` Ya que esa es la función que pasas en el provider. Sorry

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, Deje en App `<MainContextProvider value={{ setDark, dark }}>` y en el componente Header `const { setDark, dark } = useContext(MainContext);` Pero aún me sigue saliendo este error  Uncaught TypeError: setDark is not a function
    at onClick (Header.jsx:93:62)
Es como si no reconociera setDark de App

Comment: Y este es mi MainContext `import React, { createContext, useReducer, useEffect } from 'react'

//# context
export const MainContext = createContext()
export const MainProvider = MainContext.Provider
export const MainConsumer = MainContext.Consumer
`

Comment: Puedes agregar a tu pregunta el código del header para reproducir tu app, de igual manera revisate el sanbox que te coloque al final de la respuesta con todas las piezas del código

Comment: Adjunto Archivo App, Header, y MainContext en Sanbox
[link](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-cloud-hemztn?file=/src/components/layout/Header/Header.jsx)

Comment: Ya vi donde esta el posible error, te lo dejo en la respuesta actualizada

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda buen hombre, no sabes lo que significa para mí!!.